# Psycopg2 invalid json when returning postgres query

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

I am using Django to access a stored function in my postgres DB.  When I execute the function inside of Postgres, it returns doublequotes and valid json.  However, when I call the function from Django (which uses psycopg2) the doublequotes are removed and single quotes replace them.

It seems psycopg2 is doing some type of conversion to lists / dictionary in the background.  However, I need to keep the json.  Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the functionality of psycopg2 auto converting the JSON object/array by registering a no-op function with `register_default_json()`

```
psycopg2.extras.register_default_json(loads=lambda x: x)
```

### Quote from the Docs

> Psycopg automatically converts PostgreSQL json data into Python
>   objects. How can I receive strings instead? The easiest way to avoid
>   JSON parsing is to register a no-op function with
>   register_default_json():
>
> psycopg2.extras.register_default_json(loads=lambda x: x) See JSON
>   adaptation for further details.

- Source http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html?highlight=json#problems-with-type-conversions

### Additional Reading

- http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#adapt-json
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield (Not sure what you're attempting to do with the stored function but this may help alleviate the need for one)